# Stata Probit Model Interaction Term Interpretation

Tags: regression, stata

for my thesis i am currently investigating the effects of emissions on health on a regional basis. the dependent variable is bicategorical which takes the value 0 (if health is good) and 1 (if health is bad) with the exception of emissions and capita_gdp every variable is categorical:

here is an exemplary regression:

```
probit health i.year i.region##emissions age educ smoker gender urban capita_gdp, robust 
nofvlabel allbaselevels

Probit regression                               Number of obs     =     67,041
                                                Wald chi2(64)     =    5850.28
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -43026.965               Pseudo R2         =     0.0660

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                |               Robust
    health      |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           year |
             1  |          0  (base)
             2  |  -.0236149   .0290446    -0.81   0.416    -.0805412    .0333115
             3  |  -.0552885   .0343119    -1.61   0.107    -.1225386    .0119615
             4  |  -.7498958   .0521191   -14.39   0.000    -.8520474   -.6477442
                |
         region |
             1  |          0  (base)
             2  |   .3424928   .1944582     1.76   0.078    -.0386383     .723624
             3  |   .6631291    .343445     1.93   0.054    -.0100107    1.336269
             4  |   1.005453   .1809361     5.56   0.000     .6508251    1.360081
             5  |   .5202438   .2705144     1.92   0.054    -.0099547    1.050442
             6  |    .853456   .2053275     4.16   0.000     .4510215     1.25589
             7  |   -1.32784   1.329886    -1.00   0.318    -3.934369    1.278688
             8  |   .2074103   .5587633     0.37   0.710    -.8877457    1.302566
             9  |   .8778635   1.005655     0.87   0.383    -1.093184    2.848911
            10  |    .614019   .2058646     2.98   0.003     .2105317    1.017506
            11  |   1.103564   .2395228     4.61   0.000     .6341078     1.57302
            12  |  -.9928198   1.189953    -0.83   0.404    -3.325084    1.339444
            13  |   .2024027   .3014841     0.67   0.502    -.3884953    .7933008
            14  |   .8510637   .1966648     4.33   0.000     .4656078     1.23652
            15  |  -.4685238   1.062594    -0.44   0.659    -2.551171    1.614123
            16  |   .1222191   .4271317     0.29   0.775    -.7149435    .9593818
            17  |   1.777416   .9296525     1.91   0.056    -.0446694    3.599502
            18  |   .7016812   .3960197     1.77   0.076    -.0745032    1.477866
            19  |   .2164103   .2324297     0.93   0.352    -.2391436    .6719642
            20  |  -.8683004   2.079837    -0.42   0.676    -4.944707    3.208106
            21  |   .6094313   .1969787     3.09   0.002     .2233601    .9955025
            22  |   .4586692   .2175369     2.11   0.035     .0323048    .8850336
            23  |   .1376296    .316405     0.43   0.664    -.4825129    .7577721
            24  |   .8800929   .2139805     4.11   0.000     .4606989    1.299487
            25  |   .5008748    .181908     2.75   0.006     .1443417    .8574079
            26  |   .7885192   .2055236     3.84   0.000     .3857004    1.191338
            27  |   .8370192   .2066431     4.05   0.000     .4320061    1.242032
            28  |   .0342872   .3383975     0.10   0.919    -.6289597     .697534
                |
      emissions |   .2331187   .0475761     4.90   0.000     .1398713    .3263662
                |
region#c.emissions|
             1  |          0  (base)
             2  |  -.1763598   .0473856    -3.72   0.000    -.2692338   -.0834858
             3  |   .0902526   .3483855     0.26   0.796    -.5925705    .7730757
             4  |  -.2545669   .0436166    -5.84   0.000    -.3400539   -.1690798
             5  |  -.1903919   .0525988    -3.62   0.000    -.2934837   -.0873002
             6  |  -.2595892   .0565328    -4.59   0.000    -.3703914    -.148787
             7  |   .3660934   .3615611     1.01   0.311    -.3425534     1.07474
             8  |  -.1810636   .0873587    -2.07   0.038    -.3522836   -.0098436
             9  |  -.2360667   .2817683    -0.84   0.402    -.7883225     .316189
            10  |  -.2362498   .0452001    -5.23   0.000    -.3248403   -.1476593
            11  |  -.2986525   .0606014    -4.93   0.000    -.4174291    -.179876
            12  |   .4210453   .4355456     0.97   0.334    -.4326084    1.274699
            13  |  -.1393217    .063414    -2.20   0.028    -.2636109   -.0150324
            14  |  -.2428271   .0452505    -5.37   0.000    -.3315166   -.1541377
            15  |  -.1078827   .1281398    -0.84   0.400     -.359032    .1432667
            16  |  -.1121361   .0991541    -1.13   0.258    -.3064746    .0822024
            17  |  -.3670531   .1360779    -2.70   0.007    -.6337609   -.1003453
            18  |   -.241021   .1572069    -1.53   0.125    -.5491408    .0670988
            19  |  -.2128744   .0452858    -4.70   0.000    -.3016328   -.1241159
            20  |    .103139   .4313025     0.24   0.811    -.7421983    .9484763
            21  |   -.217597   .0532092    -4.09   0.000    -.3218851   -.1133089
            22  |  -.1796928   .0509009    -3.53   0.000    -.2794568   -.0799288
            23  |  -.1510797   .0529603    -2.85   0.004    -.2548799   -.0472795
            24  |  -.2589344   .0509662    -5.08   0.000    -.3588264   -.1590425
            25  |   -.231851   .0448358    -5.17   0.000    -.3197276   -.1439745
            26  |  -.2411263   .0442314    -5.45   0.000    -.3278182   -.1544344
            27  |  -.2452313   .0465597    -5.27   0.000    -.3364867    -.153976
            28  |  -.0563099   .1191566    -0.47   0.637    -.2898525    .1772328
                |
            age |   .1085835   .0049886    21.77   0.000      .098806    .1183609
           educ |  -.1802489   .0107034   -16.84   0.000    -.2012272   -.1592707
         smoker |    .080728   .0145963     5.53   0.000     .0521198    .1093362
         gender |  -.2019473   .0145416   -13.89   0.000    -.2304483   -.1734463
          urban |  -.1362217   .0112233   -12.14   0.000    -.1582189   -.1142245
     capita_gdp |  -8.36e-06   .0000194    -0.43   0.667    -.0000464    .0000297
          _cons |  -.4987429   .1638654    -3.04   0.002    -.8199132   -.1775726
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is, how can I exactly interpret the coefficients of emissions and the interaction of region.c#emissions on the dependent variable ? To my understanding the coefficient of emissions for region 1 is the base level and the coefficient of emissions in region 2 is lower than region 1 by -.176 ?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Two extra things worth noting:

1. Interactions work both ways. So the interaction coefficient tells you that the emissions effect is 0.176 smaller in region 2, but also that the effect of being in region 2 is 0.176 smaller if emissions are one unit larger. That also means you cannot directly interpret any coefficient involved in the interaction (region & emissions) as they both depend on each other.
2. Stata has an excellent `margins` and `marginsplot` command that calculates for you what the coefficients are at particular levels of region and/or emissions. It has a bit of a learning curve, but if you get the hang of it you can produce beautiful graphs to illustrate the interaction effect that will be much more informative than a long regression table.
   There are many tutorials online on how to use margins and there's also [this presentation by Ben Jann](https://ideas.repec.org/p/boc/dsug13/11.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you really helped me. I have a further question: In this output there are several regions which are negative and have a higher coefficient than the base level. For example region 4. The base level has a coefficient of (0.23) and region 4 of (-0.25). This would indicate, that in region 4, increasing emissions actually would lead to less negative health outcomes which is quite counterintuitive... How can I possibly interpret this?

Comment: Generally speaking, there's three options:
1) the results are correct, we just don't understand why
2) the counterintuitive result is not significant (it's just noise)
3) your model suffers from omitted variable bias. E.g. if higher emission regions also have better healthcare systems (because they are richer, more socialist, ...) you could find that some regions have both higher emissions and better health

Comment: Thank you so much Dan ! You really helped me :)